DataSource item's fields object is not coming in the layout service in graphql
I have one footer component available on the page design and that page design is applied on all of the pages of the site. When I try to run the site locally using next js localhost:3000 application then props used in the footer's .tsx component are giving null error.
When I checked the response of the layout service in the preview GraphQL then I noticed that fields object was not coming. I checked on the dev environment and there the object is coming fine. So, I took the complete content package from dev and installed it locally so that everything is the same as dev but still preview graphQL doesn't return the fields object for datasource item.
For example, see the response on the Dev environment:

Below is the response from local preview GraphQL:

Now not sure, what is missing or where to check/debug why the layout is not giving the fields object in preview.
Note: You may see the different data source ID in the preview, because I was testing by duplicating the actual data source item, but with the same data source as well the fields object is not coming.
Edit-1: I was able to find that somehow the Component GraphQL query is messing due to which the fields object is not returning.
query GlobalFooter($datasource: String!) {
  item: item(path: $datasource, language: "en") {
    id
    Copyright: field(name: "Copyright") {
      jsonValue
    }
    LegalCopy: field(name: "LegalCopy") {
      jsonValue
    }
    Logo: field(name: "Logo") {
      jsonValue
    }
    LogoLink: field(name: "LogoLink") {
      jsonValue
    }

When I removed the query then fields object was coming in the response as below:
"componentName": "GlobalFooter",
                          "dataSource": "{B1XXXXX-F0D2-46E2-81A4-3E06BXXXXXX}",
                          "params": {
                            "DynamicPlaceholderId": "1",
                            "FieldNames": "Default"
                          },
                          "fields": {
                            "Copyright": {
                              "value": "© 2018-{CurrentYear} all rights reserved"
                            },
                            "LegalCopy": {
                              "value": "Legal Copy field data to be inserted here"
                            },
                            "Logo": {
                              "value": {
                                "src": "https://xmcloudcm.localhost/-/media/Project/demo/demo/Images/Logos/demo/demo.svg?h=119&iar=0&w=224&hash=2C568C2DE0xxxxx8481xxxxx",
                                "alt": "demo",
                                "width": "224",
                                "height": "119"
                              }
                            },
                            "LogoLink": {
                              "value": {
                                "class": "",
                                "id": "{AB606403-7EE4-443D-BDE9-XXXXXXXX}",

Not sure what is the issue with the query, any idea?

George, Do you have any custom content Resolvers written in the solution? If yes, there is a possibility, where it might be failing in one of those, leading to Footer specific datasource fields not being visible. If there is a custom content resolver, try commenting it out and checking once.

@VarunShringarpure, no, there is no resolver selected for the rendering.

@GeorgeCarter - Can you try the same component in a different placeholder and check the layout service output? And is this behavior coming in Partial Design?

Hi @DebtanuBiswas, thanks for giving the hint. I was to find the reason is due to Component GraphQL query field but why it is happening that I am not sure. Please check my question I have edited my finding.

@DebtanuBiswas Any idea for this please?

@GeorgeCarter - Taking a wild guess, however can you Rebuild the master index once and check the output. Also for the master DB, the Depth parameter of GQL is different than the edge. Can you please try adding this config and check which I will provide as an answer

Please try and add the below config. This might resolve the issue:
    <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"
               xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/"
               xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/"
               xmlns:env="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/env/">
    <sitecore>
    <api>
      <GraphQL>
        <defaults>
          <security>
            <publicService type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Hosting.Security.GraphQLSecurity, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL">
              <complexityConfiguration type="GraphQL.Validation.Complexity.ComplexityConfiguration, GraphQL">
                <maxDepth>50</maxDepth>
                <maxComplexity>20000</maxComplexity>
              </complexityConfiguration>
            </publicService>
          </security>
        </defaults>
      </GraphQL>
    </api>
    <layoutService>
      <serializationMaxDepth>8</serializationMaxDepth>
    </layoutService>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>


I increased maxDepth to 60 and maxComplexity from 20000 to 100000 then it worked

Glad it helped @GeorgeCarter
